# XPath: match multiple elements in one expression

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to do this (using lxml):

```
//*[@id="32808345" or @id="33771423" or @id="15929470" or @id="33771117" or @id="15929266"]
```

in order to get all elements, no matter what tag, with the specified id's. I'm getting the following traceback:

```
invalid attribute predicate
```

this is how I'm generating the str (if that is relevant to the problem):

```
refs = ' or '.join('@id="%s"' % ref for ref in refs[0:5])
elements = etree.iterfind('//*[%s]' % refs)
```

EDIT, with the below solution I'm getting this error:

```
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1201, in lxml.etree._Element.iterchildren (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:36294)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2163, in lxml.etree.ElementChildIterator.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:45331)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2118, in lxml.etree._ElementTagMatcher._initTagMatch (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:44913)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1413, in lxml.etree._getNsTag (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:21412)
ValueError: Empty tag name
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the python xpath implementation entails, but the xpath works for me in other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal way to do this is using the single pipe operator, I believe?

```
//*[@id="20"] | //*[@id="30"] | ... etc.
```

Do you have a snippet of the XML you're trying to do this on?

Comment: Based on that XML, the above works. Is that what you were looking for?

According to http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx using the above with ID's 2 and 7 matches members 2 and 7 in the XML.

Comment: ah, ok, you changed your post, now it seems to work.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with that :/ It looks like a problem with lxml.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `xpath` method instead of `iterfind`.

I think the `iterfind` method doesn't accept all XPath expressions.